# Ajax success call is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
        data: '{frequency:   "' + $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text() + 
               ', reportYear: "' + $('#txtReportYear').text() + 
               ', reportMonth: "' + $('#txtReportMonth').text() + 
               ', reportDay:   "' + $('#txtReportDay').text() +
               ', reportOption: "' + $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text() +
               ', reportRegion: "' + $('#txtReportRegion').text() +
               ', reportSchedule: "' + $('#ddlReportSchedule').text() + 
               ', reportRegion:   "' + $('#txtReportRegion').text() + '"}', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //            dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data.d != "") {
                $('#rptDisplay').text(data.d);
            }

            alert("1");
        },
        failure: function () {
            //                $('#rptDisplay').text("Error");
            alert("2");
        }
```

I think I made some mistake sending the parameters since the `success` section is not called.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the `failure: function () { ... }` fire? On a different note, it appears that you're attempting to manually create JSON to send across the wire? You should consider building your JavaScript object normally and then call `JSON.parse(obj);` on said object to generate the JSON. I also think jQuery handles this for you internally, but I'm not sure so don't hold me to that...

Comment: What *does* happen?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: doesn't data accept an object, not a strange string???

Comment: Don't you have to JSON.stringify() your object when sending data?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    frequency: $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text(),
    ...
}),
```

Not sure if you will have to remove the charset part in here.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `data` to an actual object:-

```
data: {frequency: $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text(), 
       reportYear: $('#txtReportYear').text(), 
       reportMonth: $('#txtReportMonth').text(), 
       reportDay: $('#txtReportDay').text(),
       reportOption: $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text(),
       reportRegion: $('#txtReportRegion').text(),
       reportSchedule: $('#ddlReportSchedule').text(),
       reportRegion: $('#txtReportRegion').text()},
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build the JSON object ahead of time like this.  I removed unnecessary code and simplified it a little.  If the there is a problem in the call, the 'error' function is called, not 'failure'.  Make sure the URL you are calling is valid.  I'm assuming this script is being run in the same folder where the aspx file exists.

```
var jsonObject = { 
  frequency: $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text(),
  reportYear: $('#txtReportYear').text(),
  reportMonth: $('#txtReportMonth').text(),
  reportDay: $('#txtReportDay').text(),
  reportOption: $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text(),
  reportRegion: $('#txtReportRegion').text(),
  reportSchedule: $('#ddlReportSchedule').text(),
  reportRegion: $('#txtReportRegion').text()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
    data: jsonObject, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("error");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Of course, you could also just build an Object Literal directly inside the 'data' node of the AJAX call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
    data: { 
      frequency: $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text(),
      reportYear: $('#txtReportYear').text(),
      reportMonth: $('#txtReportMonth').text(),
      reportDay: $('#txtReportDay').text(),
      reportOption: $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text(),
      reportRegion: $('#txtReportRegion').text(),
      reportSchedule: $('#ddlReportSchedule').text(),
      reportRegion: $('#txtReportRegion').text()
    }, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("error");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Either way works, the second way might be slightly more efficient since you're not storing the JSON object in a variable but the first way I did it makes the AJAX call a little more readable, and unless memory is extremely tight (which I doubt it is, in your situation) than i'd stick with my first example.  Personal preference.

Comment: Note that dataType refers to the type of the response data, not the data you are sending.

Comment: I just left that in there b/c it was in his original code.  Yeah, dataType isn't necessary but it will help evaluate the response to the proper format.  It's fine if he's sure it's a JSON response he's getting back, otherwise, might be best to just leave that out.  I usually leave it out, myself.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes in the data object don't match up. Add an end double quote before the start of your next property.

```
data: '{frequency:   "' + $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text() + 
           '", reportYear: "' + $('#txtReportYear').text() + 
           '", reportMonth: "' + $('#txtReportMonth').text() + 
           '", reportDay:   "' + $('#txtReportDay').text() +
           '", reportOption: "' + $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text() +
           '", reportRegion: "' + $('#txtReportRegion').text() +
           '", reportSchedule: "' + $('#ddlReportSchedule').text() + 
           '", reportRegion:   "' + $('#txtReportRegion').text() + '"}',
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be syntax issues with the way you constructed your JSON data object. There are double quotes missing to enclose the values and there aren't any double quotes around the strings, try rewriting it as such:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/GeneratePdfs",
  data: '{"frequency": "' + $('#ddlReportFrequency option:selected').text() + 
        '", "reportYear": "' + $('#txtReportYear').text() + 
        '", "reportMonth": "' + $('#txtReportMonth').text() + 
        '", "reportDay": "' + $('#txtReportDay').text() +
        '", "reportOption": "' + $('#ddlReportOption option:selected').text() +
        '", "reportRegion": "' + $('#txtReportRegion').text() +
        '", "reportSchedule": "' + $('#ddlReportSchedule').text() + 
        '", "reportRegion": "' + $('#txtReportRegion').text() + '"}', 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  // dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    debugger;
    if (data.d != "") {
      $('#rptDisplay').text(data.d);
    }
    alert("1");
  },
  failure: function () {
    // $('#rptDisplay').text("Error");
    alert("2");
  }
});
```

See: http://www.json.org ;)